# replace number with pictures jquery memory game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a memory game.If a user clicks on two table cells that contain equal numbers it will be displayed and will remain displayed. If the numbers contained in two cells are not equal, they will be hidden again. The game ends when all numbers have been turned.
And now i want to replace the numbers with pictures.
I put pictures adresses in "cards" array,but it doesn't work.

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    .container{
      width: 1088px;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    .card{
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
      height: 150px;
      width: 200px;
      background: blue;
      text-align: center;
    
    }
    
    </style>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="card unmatched "></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched "></div>
          <div class="card unmatched "></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
          <div class="card unmatched"></div>
    
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var app={
          cards: [1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,6],
          init: function(){
            app.shuffle();
    
    
          },
          shuffle: function(){
            var random = 0;
            var temp = 0;
            for(i = 1; i< app.cards.length; i++){
              random = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
              temp = app.cards[i];
              app.cards[i]= app.cards[random];
              app.cards[random] = temp;
    
            }
            app.assignCards();
            console.log('Shuffled Card Array' +app.cards);
          },
          assignCards: function(){
            $('.card').each(function(index){
            $(this).attr("data-card-value",  app.cards[index]);
            });
            app.clickHandlers();
          },
          clickHandlers: function(){
            $('.card').on('click',function(){
            $(this).html('<p>' +$(this).data('cardValue')+'</p>').addClass('selected');
            app.checkMatch();
            });
          },
          checkMatch: function () {
            if($('.selected').length === 2){
              if($('.selected').first().data('cardValue') == $('.selected').last().data('cardValue')){
                $('.selected').each(function(){
                  $(this).animate({opacity:2 }).removeClass('unmatched');
                });
                $('.selected').each(function(){
                  $(this).removeClass('selected');
                });
              app.checkWin()
              }else{
                setTimeout(function(){
                  $('.selected').each(function(){
                    $(this).html(' ').removeClass('selected');
                  });
                },1000);
                //flip cards back over
              }
            }
          },
          checkWin:function(){
            if($('.unmatched').length === 0){
              $('.container').html('<h1>You Won</h1>');
            }
          }
    
        };
        app .init();
        });
        </script>
      </body>
      </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put the image URLs as `src` attributes in `img` elements. Here's a simple fix.

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<style>
.container{
  width: 1088px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card{
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 150px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  text-align: center;

}

</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>
      <div class="card unmatched"></div>

    </div>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var app={
      cards: ['https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?2',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?2',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?3',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?3',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?4',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?4',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?5',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?5',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?6',
              'https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png?6'],
      init: function(){
        app.shuffle();


      },
      shuffle: function(){
        var random = 0;
        var temp = 0;
        for(i = 1; i< app.cards.length; i++){
          random = Math.round(Math.random() * i);
          temp = app.cards[i];
          app.cards[i]= app.cards[random];
          app.cards[random] = temp;

        }
        app.assignCards();
        console.log('Shuffled Card Array' +app.cards);
      },
      assignCards: function(){
        $('.card').each(function(index){
        $(this).attr("data-card-value",  app.cards[index]);
        });
        app.clickHandlers();
      },
      clickHandlers: function(){
        $('.card').on('click',function(){
        $(this).html('<img src="' +$(this).data('cardValue')+'" />').addClass('selected');
        app.checkMatch();
        });
      },
      checkMatch: function () {
        if($('.selected').length === 2){
          if($('.selected').first().data('cardValue') == $('.selected').last().data('cardValue')){
            $('.selected').each(function(){
              $(this).animate({opacity:2 }).removeClass('unmatched');
            });
            $('.selected').each(function(){
              $(this).removeClass('selected');
            });
          app.checkWin()
          }else{
            setTimeout(function(){
              $('.selected').each(function(){
                $(this).html(' ').removeClass('selected');
              });
            },1000);
            //flip cards back over
          }
        }
      },
      checkWin:function(){
        if($('.unmatched').length === 0){
          $('.container').html('<h1>You Won</h1>');
        }
      }

    };
    app .init();
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method in `clickHandler` and instead of showing the text and an `img` tag.

```
$('.card').on('click',function(){
    $(this).html('<img width="200" height="150" src="'+$(this).data('cardValue')+'"/>').addClass('selected');
    app.checkMatch();
});
```

Comment: It does not work as it should. It keeps only a pair open. :-? Why?

Comment: I've updated the answer so that it's clear what the code for `clickHandler` should be. Here's also working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7bkp4fr4/

Comment: Thank you very much all!